# How to use SystemMediaTransportControls in WPF Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player

Is there any way to create an SystemMediaTransportControls-object in WPF?

I followed [this](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/) guide to access the Windows 10 APIs from my WPF-Application. I can call the class but I can't create an object. In a UWP-App you create it like this:

```
SystemMediaTransportControls smtp = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
```

But by calling this method in WPF, I'm getting an `"Invalid window handle"` exception at this line.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SystemMediaTransportControls smtp;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //SMTP Einrichten
        smtp = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
    }

[...]
}
```

Apparently, `GetForCurrentView()` is not working in WPF but what to use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SystemMediaTransportControls isn't supported in desktop apps. It can only be used in UWP apps.

See [UWP APIs callable from a classic desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/apiindex/uwp-apis-callable-from-a-classic-desktop-app), which says:

> **If the DualApiPartition attribute is not listed**
>
> In this case, the API
>   is not allowed to be called from a classic desktop app.
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button is an example.

[SystemMediaTransportControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SystemMediaTransportControls) does not have the DualApiPartition attribute.

The **How do I know which APIs are available?** section of guide you linked references the list of [UWP APIs available to a packaged desktop app (Desktop Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api#both) , and this also does not list SystemMediatTransportControls as available.

Comment: Well, [Firefox have found a way to use it](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/widget/windows/WindowsSMTCProvider.cpp#102). And that's certainly a desktop application. But I don't understand that code.

Comment: "Windows desktop applications can integrate with the system media transport controls by using the ISystemMediaTransportControls interface." -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/mediatransport/media-transport-controls-portal

Answer (score 1):

You should install the [Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts) NuGet package. Then you will be able to interact with System Media Transport Controls in your WPF project.

Here is an example which prints some media information, then tries to pause the media:

```
var sessionManager = await GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.RequestAsync();
var mediaProperties = await sessionManager.GetCurrentSession().TryGetMediaPropertiesAsync();

Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", mediaProperties?.Artist, mediaProperties?.Title);
Console.WriteLine($"Status: {sessionManager.GetCurrentSession().GetPlaybackInfo().PlaybackStatus}");

await sessionManager.GetCurrentSession().TryPauseAsync();
```