# C# bindings for ISystemMediaTransportControls

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, .net-5

Does anybody have information where I can locate bindings for the ISystemMediaTransportControls interface?

I'm developing a desktop application in C# and .NET 5. I would use the UWP SystemMediaTransportControls class (see [How to use SystemMediaTransportControls in WPF Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292478/how-to-use-systemmediatransportcontrols-in-wpf-application)), but this API is not available for Desktop Apps. For desktop apps, you have to use the ISystemMediaTransportControls interface (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/mediatransport/isystemmediatransportcontrols) which is I think is a COM+ interface and based on docs It's not available in the UWP API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it without the need of the interface. Under .NET 5 you can accquire an instance by with the following static property `Windows.Media.Playback.BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls`

Comment: Doesn't that require UWP? Did you have to add a reference to a Nuget or library to get this?

Comment: No, you don't need a nuget package, at least under .NET 5. Simply replace the net5.0- windows target framework with net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0. This will allow you to use UWP api's that are present in the 1809 or older build of Windows 10. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance